# Control with play/stop/pause e.t.c. buttons for media playing

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls

does somebody know if there is a free control or somebody is selling a control with buttons play/stop/pause e.t.c. (like the ones of windows media player)
that can be used for media playing.

I do not want that the control plays the media but i want only the buttons and the play progress bar.

Also do you know of a control where the user can select segments of the media file ?

Thanks !

Comment: This kind of control would be made best in `WPF`. However you can make it using `Winform` with more code. Maybe using `Image buttons` is OK.

Comment: Why not create your own controls?

Answer (score 1):

Something like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35104/gTrackBar-A-Custom-TrackBar-UserControl-VB-NET)? 
As for buttons, you could search for some pretty PNGs and embed them in buttons. Easy, free, and quick to do.

If you simply want to *get it done*, see [this](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=101752) beast. I have not used it, but it looks like it could handle the media hassle for you.